# One RAID1 missing after reboot

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, raid-1, mdadm

I'm using Open Media Vault 3 that is based on Debian 8.

I already have a RAID1 of 2x4TB WD Caviar Red, and now I'm tring to build a RAID1 with two Seagate Ironwolf 6TB.

Whe I build it anything is fine and I can create an ext4 partition on it and use it without a problem.

The problem is that every time that I reboot only the new RAID1 disappears. The old one is working just fine without any problem.

If I look with gparted both hard drives has no partion, like I never built a RAID1 with them, but if I look with testdisk I can find every file.
Also if I try to rebuild the RAID the files will still be there, so I'm not losing my data.

After the reboot I tried to see if I could find md0 but this is the result:

```
mdadm --detail --scan

ARRAY /dev/md127 metadata=1.2 name=NAS:Data UUID=ed696fd2:96feba4f:ab44fb72:b800fb01
```

No md0, only 127!
I also tried with this command:

```
root@Delibird:~# mdadm -Es
ARRAY /dev/md/Data  metadata=1.2 UUID=ed696fd2:96feba4f:ab44fb72:b800fb01 name=NAS:Data
```

and still no result.

This is the conf file (/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf)

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
# Note, if no DEVICE line is present, then "DEVICE partitions" is assumed.
# To avoid the auto-assembly of RAID devices a pattern that CAN'T match is
# used if no RAID devices are configured.
DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md127 metadata=1.2 name=NAS:Data UUID=ed696fd2:96feba4f:ab44fb72:b800fb01
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=Delibird:Telefilm UUID=4de2d990:37fa60cf:b34e2c9e:63b4d0ca
```

I tried to update the conf for the boot with

```
update-initramfs -u
```

But even after that, the RAID1 is still missing after the reboot :(

I finally tried wit this command:

```
 mdadm --assemble --scan
```

but it did nothing

How should I do? I really don't know how to solve my problem!

Comment: Put `mdadm --assemble --scan` into `/etc/rc.local` and write a bugreport: https://bugtracker.openmediavault.org/